# Difficulties with cefsharp showing a website

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, cefsharp

I want to put a cefsharp browser into a windows 10 touchscreen device. I'm encountering problems with just a basic coding to show a website. Below is my code:

```
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitBrowser();
    }

    public void InitBrowser()
    {
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

When I run the app, the below appear:

[image]

Seems like the browser size become smaller than the window size.

And when I scroll down, the below appear:

[image]

Seems like it become normal already.

But when I scroll up again, the same problem happen again:

[image]

The coding is just basic only. I try it on my laptop and its no problem. But I try it on this touchscreen device will have this problem. Means not all device will have this problem. Do you guys know what went wrong?

Comment: Are you using a `DPI > 100%`? If so you need to make your app `DPI` aware.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-click on your exe -> compatibility -> check "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings"